# Is kiwi safe to eat during antibiotic therapy?

Tags: antibiotics, biochemistry

I look for information about if it is safe to eat a Kiwi fruit during antibiotic therapy.

I know that the fruit is source of calcium so it can weaken absorption of drug so time delay before and after taking the medicine.

I google through many pages in Polish and English. I found potential alergic effect and influence on blood clotting but no word about interactions with antibiotics is it safe or dangerous.

Is kiwi free from any substance that can prevent break down an antibiotic medicine into simpler substances, as citrus would?

Comment: Welcome to MedicalSciences.SE! Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. For [reasons mentioned in this post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411) and in [ask], we require prior research information when asking questions. *See [this list of helpful resources](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/a/784)*. Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject, what made you ask this question, and any problems you are having understanding your research. If you found nothing, what did you Google?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104517/discussion-on-question-by-adam-mierzwiak-is-kiwi-safe-to-eat-during-antibiotic-t).

Comment: If you would specify which antibiotics are used in the antibiotics therapy then it would be easier to find the food-drug interaction.

Comment: I am interested in Penicillin V group